# back up a DB to another DB on seperate servers?

Tags: php, mysql

Alrighty, i've got a processor intensive program i'm running on a locally hosted server, i recently bought a web hosting service and want to frequently update the website's DB with the local server's DB information but cannot figure out how to go about doing this.

I'm using PDO and the local server is a Debian Distro, the remote server is hosted on JustHost. I'm hoping there's a way to update the remote without having to just dump the local's SQL file and upload it to the remotes.

Comment: Have you heard of **mysql replication**? EDIT: if not, then google it ;)

Comment: replication does a 1:1 mirroring. if you're doing devel on your local machine, you probably DON'T want replication, since any test/buggy data/structures you put into the local server will also get automatically pushed to live.

Comment: @MarcB what would you suggest then?